# What is the definition of song in the speech to song illusion?

Tags: music

I have been looking at Diana Deutsch's "speech-to-song" illusion and I don't understand what she means by song. I have written a lot of music and I don't hear anything that sounds like a song in her samples.

http://deutsch.ucsd.edu/psychology/pages.php?i=212

Can someone clarify what exactly she means by "song"? I read through a related [paper](http://deutsch.ucsd.edu/pdf/JASA-2011_129_2245-2252.pdf) by here that seemed like it would have such a definition but didn't find one.